# ROCA with unknown M and g

Tags: rsa, roca

Trying to upsolve "notsosmart -  hxp CTF 2017"

https://2017.ctf.link/internal/challenge/5c8119ca-bfed-444a-968d-1cc9bff27bfb.html

This server code was given during the CTF, letting you get multiple values of n:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import randrange
from gmpy2 import *
from fast import random_prime

p, q = random_prime(), random_prime()
assert is_prime(p) and is_prime(q)
assert gcd(65537, (p - 1) * (q - 1)) == 1

n = p * q

m = open('flag.txt', 'rb').read().strip()
assert len(m) <= 100
m = int.from_bytes(m, 'big')
m |= randrange(0, n, 1 << 800)

print('n = {:#x}'.format(n))
print('c = {:#x}'.format(pow(m, 65537, n)))
```

But this code was only released AFTER the CTF ended:

```
import random
import gmpy2
random = random.SystemRandom()

m = 0xb107cff9bc81dc39662bc077f2dddc1f2345cf31e6af31a1a22b01c5c88488d3ccdc6b893c7a4b6171ad475e801db52542
o = 0x114fede0c299ca7ee8d431d71a582dd30df0dff236b96939a64037186703f424f7c5160000000000000000000000000000
g = 0x5e90d99feb75d04a3cb15a55cb9ea7dbdd03879a18b49d4108f18dc012f64b02324365accf82aad52bf0d1c117a60d5b6b

def random_prime():

    while True:
        p = pow(g, random.randrange(o), m)
        p += random.randrange(0, 2 ** 512, m)
        if gmpy2.is_prime(p):
            break

    return p
```

If I just take M and g from this secret file then I can find a good M' etc and do the normal ROCA attack and factor in a few seconds.

But how could you solve it without knowing them?

M could be bruted somewhat easily since it's a primorial

But idk how to find g or something related to g....

Comment: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/53906/18298

Comment: No, my focus is on, given a list of vulnerable modulii generated with the same large unknown M and g, finding some other compatible M_ and g_ to do the ROCA attack with.

This is what the author said:

"seeing many samples allows you to deduce a sufficiently large set of small primes that are probably contained in m, and a generator that'll work for the attack can be guessed from this as well 

indeed it's not necessary to obtain *the* value of m or g: we just have to find such values which are compatible with the (many) observed ns"

I'm stuck on the 'a generator can also be guessed'

Answer (score -1):

got it, since the ns are a power of g you can choose g=some n

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63814)

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/63814)